# Ms Access crashes out when its callback function called from a dll's thread function

Tags: vba, ms-access, dll, callback

I have made a dll with C for use in an Ms Access vba project. The dll makes use of a vba callback function. According to MS documentation the vba callback function has to be in a module and not in a form's code. Inside the callback function I set a form's filter property. But because of this the Access crashes when the execution it arrives there!!! Why? Other references to form's components have no problem (for example when I set the value of the form's textbox)
Thanks

The C dll code compiled with VS 2017:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <tchar.h>

typedef void(__stdcall * CallbackFunction)();

DWORD __stdcall ThreadFunc(CallbackFunction Callback) {

Callback();
return 0;
}


__declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall message(CallbackFunction Callback) {
    // Array to store thread handles
    HANDLE Array_Of_Thread_Handles[1];
    Array_Of_Thread_Handles[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, ThreadFunc, Callback, 0, NULL);
}
```

And here is the code that call the dll function "message" from within vba

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Call message(AddressOf Callback)
End Sub
```

The vba Declaration of dll

```
Public Declare Sub message Lib "MonitoringDirectoryDLL.dll" Alias "_message@4" (ByVal Callback As Long)
```

The vba callback subroutine (resides on a Module according to MS documentation)

```
Public Sub Callback()
    On Error Resume Next
    Forms("MyForm").txtTest="test" 'this line executed well and the string "test" appears ok in the form.
    Forms("MyForm").Filter="" 'in this line Access crashes out
    Forms("MyForm").FilterOn=True
End Sub
```

UPDATE 1

I found that the problem exists only when the vba Callback Sub is called from the Thread function (ThreadFunc). If it is called from within dll "message" function form's filter is set ok (!!!)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Your question is very generic, it's very likely you have an incompatibility somewhere, for example by calling the callback function the wrong way.

Comment: Ok Erik... I have added all the code I use... thanks

Comment: As I said in UPDATE 1 the problem exists only when the callback is called from within thread function. If it is called from within message function everything is ok

Comment: Certainly a possibility. My C is rusty but I believe you can't just call a 32-bit function pointer from a 64-bit application.

Comment: My wrong... sorry... I checked the dll and is 32-bit. My MS Access 2010 is also 32-bit... so this is not the problem (even if Windows 7 is 64bit). For this reason I deleted the comment.